# Exporting/Importing all local MySQL databases - Error #1046 - No database selected - Multiple databases

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, mamp

I recently purchased a new MacBook and I am currently working on porting all my databases over from my old one. On my old MacBook I went into PHPMyAdmin through MAMP and did an export selecting every local database(over a dozen separate databases exported into a single file). I've installed MAMP on my new computer and I am trying to import all the databases but I am getting the following error:

```
MySQL said:

#1046 - No database selected
```

Looking at the SQL file in SublimeText, I can see where it shows which database each table belongs to in the comments:

```
-- Database: `magento`
```

Is there an easy way to modify the SQL file to create those databases and import the tables into their respective databases?

Thanks!

Comment: put a `use myDbName;` at the top

Comment: Won't that import everything into a single database? This SQL file contains over a dozen separate databases.

Comment: The duplicate question does not pertain to my question as they are working with a single database whereas I am working with several.

Comment: You have no db selected. So figure where in your code you need to do what you need to do. Including breaking up the file or putting in the `use` appropriately

Comment: You have no db selected. I am not reopening it. Someone else can.